# Parsing a JSON to a String Line

Tags: android, json, django, google-maps, retrofit

I'm using retrofit to get a route from google maps api, it returns a JSON but i need it in a single String line, is there a way to parse it? im using android studio and currently i can receive the JSON object but i need it as a String line to be able to get all the points and draw route in the map.
also, my backend server is using DJANGO, is there a way to do it using DJANGO or is it easier to do it in the android cellphone?
if found how to do it using httpurlconnections with the BufferedInputStream and the BufferedReader, but i need it using retrofit, thanks

here is the code for httpurlconnections :

```
public class JSONParser {

    String charset = "UTF-8";
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    DataOutputStream wr;
    StringBuilder result;
    URL urlObj;
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    StringBuilder sbParams;
    String paramsString;

    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      HashMap<String, String> params, boolean encode) {

        sbParams = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        for (String key : params.keySet()) {
            try {
                if (i != 0){
                    sbParams.append("&");
                }
                if (encode) {
                    sbParams.append(key).append("=")
                            .append(URLEncoder.encode(params.get(key), charset));
                }
                else{
                    sbParams.append(key).append("=")
                            .append(params.get(key));
                }

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
        }
        if(method.equals("GET")){
            // request method is GET

            if (sbParams.length() != 0) {
                url += "?" + sbParams.toString();
            }

            Log.d("JSONParser", "full GET url: " + url);

            try {
                urlObj = new URL(url);

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(false);

                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

                conn.connect();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        try {
            //Receive the response from the server
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            String line;
            result = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }

            Log.d("JSON Parser", "result: " + result.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        conn.disconnect();

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(result.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON Object
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

here is an example json that i get from the server:

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "overview_polyline": {
        "points": "ei||BhfgvRbAs@rAqAx@_AjAeB^w@v@uBv@_DJo@vAx@`DhBp@^rAiINo@n@iB\iAxC`BjBlA~@f@~NnIfDjBz@d@nEjCL?XA~GzD`FrCFJLHrA`ApD`Cx@d@d@TxAv@fIpEdFvC~DzBrKjGdLtG~HrEfI~EtAx@fDjBdQ~JvCdB`EvBjGpDvMzH~MzHvAz@jPjJrJtFpJnFdE|BjHfEt@b@hBbAtGtD`E~BjEjCnHhEtD|BdH|D~NnIrPtJxHjErDxBtQbKb@ZPVFF~BpAtLbHb@X^m@BYp@sBx@uBpCd@"
      },
      "warnings": [],
      "bounds": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 20.6301062,
          "lng": -103.4199452
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 20.5577814,
          "lng": -103.4636853
        }
      },
      "waypoint_order": [],
      "summary": "Av. López Mateos Sur/México 15",
      "copyrights": "Map data ©2015 Google, INEGI",
      "legs": [
        {
          "distance": {
            "text": "9.9 km",
            "value": 9878
          },
          "end_address": "Calle Ramon Corona 705, 45640 San Agustín, Jal., Mexico",
          "via_waypoint": [],
          "start_address": "Corona Boreal 4144, Arboledas, 45070 Zapopan, Jal., Mexico",
          "duration": {
            "text": "14 mins",
            "value": 833
          },
          "steps": [
            {
              "html_instructions": "Head <b>southeast</b> on <b>Corona Boreal</b> toward <b>Sirio</b>",
              "distance": {
                "text": "0.4 km",
                "value": 442
              },
              "travel_mode": "DRIVING",
              "start_location": {
                "lat": 20.6301062,
                "lng": -103.4251706
              },
              "polyline": {
                "points": "ei||BhfgvRBATOTORQXUPSRSRS\_@Z_@t@gAT]Ra@JUZw@Z}@Nk@HYLk@Nm@Jo@"
              },
              "duration": {
                "text": "2 mins",
                "value": 94
              },
              "end_location": {
                "lat": 20.6278997,
                "lng": -103.4217575
              }
            },
            {
              "html_instructions": "Turn <b>right</b> onto <b>Calle Sagitario</b>",
              "distance": {
                "text": "0.2 km",
                "value": 182
              },
              "maneuver": "turn-right",
              "duration": {
                "text": "1 min",
                "value": 40
              },
              "travel_mode": "DRIVING",
              "polyline": {
                "points": "k{{|B~pfvRvAx@xAz@fAl@\R"
              },
              "start_location": {
                "lat": 20.6278997,
                "lng": -103.4217575
              },
              "end_location": {
                "lat": 20.6265019,
                "lng": -103.4226761
              }
            },
            {
              "html_instructions": "Turn <b>left</b> at the 3rd cross street onto <b>Galileo Galilei</b>",
              "distance": {
                "text": "0.3 km",
                "value": 322
              },
              "maneuver": "turn-left",
              "duration": {
                "text": "1 min",
                "value": 54
              },
              "travel_mode": "DRIVING",
              "polyline": {
                "points": "sr{|BvvfvRRJdAyGLo@F[FSDQh@wA\iA"
              },
              "start_location": {
                "lat": 20.6265019,
                "lng": -103.4226761
              },
              "end_location": {
                "lat": 20.6255063,
                "lng": -103.4199452
              }
            },
            {
              "html_instructions": "Turn <b>right</b> onto <b>Av. López Mateos Sur</b> (signs for <b>Colima</b>/<b>Periferico</b>)",
              "distance": {
                "text": "0.8 km",
                "value": 832
              },
              "maneuver": "turn-right",
              "duration": {
                "text": "1 min",
                "value": 87
              },
              "travel_mode": "DRIVING",
              "polyline": {
                "points": "ml{|BtefvRxC`B\TlAv@`@RB@NHHFz@d@xAx@pFbDvBjATLFBdCtABB`@RXPnEjC"
              },
              "start_location": {
                "lat": 20.6255063,
                "lng": -103.4199452
              },
              "end_location": {
                "lat": 20.6191352,
                "lng": -103.4241374
              }
            },
            {
              "html_instructions": "Keep <b>left</b> to continue on <b>Av. López Mateos Sur</b>/<b>México 15</b>",
              "distance": {
                "text": "7.4 km",
                "value": 7421
              },
              "maneuver": "keep-left",
              "duration": {
                "text": "7 mins",
                "value": 436
              },
              "travel_mode": "DRIVING",
              "polyline": {
                "points": "sdz|Bz_gvRL?F?PAxCdBdCtA`FrCFJBBHDBBnA|@pClB^R\RNHJFB@`@Rh@Tn@`@rEfCrBhAnBfAtBnAzA|@bB|@xJzFXNpEhC\R`DjBRJv@b@nAr@dAl@pBlAFBjBjAn@^|@h@dAn@TL?@HD@@JFJDz@h@r@`@TLLHnAp@|BrAx@d@vAv@tBnAnAr@`@VLH~@f@~BtAVNbAh@|BlAn@^@@nCzAhAr@j@\rBjAlEhChBfA|@f@zDvB~D`Cd@XPJdAn@bFtCfItEbAj@f@XnC|AvBpAjAp@hCvAx@f@`B|@h@\zC~AdDlBdCxATJ\T@@VLDDPJx@b@xAx@@@`B|@vAz@pC`Bn@\nAx@zBpA~BtAb@VtAv@t@b@zCfBXTjBfAxDtBt@`@lAr@f@ZrI|EhFxCf@ZhCzAvCbBjAn@bAj@v@d@pBhA`Al@d@X^Rj@\l@\fCvAhGlDtC~Ab@Z"
              },
              "start_location": {
                "lat": 20.6191352,
                "lng": -103.4241374
              },
              "end_location": {
                "lat": 20.5623663,
                "lng": -103.4615311
              }
            },
            {
              "html_instructions": "Slight <b>right</b> toward <b>Calle Ramon Corona</b>",
              "distance": {
                "text": "0.4 km",
                "value": 392
              },
              "maneuver": "turn-slight-right",
              "duration": {
                "text": "1 min",
                "value": 52
              },
              "travel_mode": "DRIVING",
              "polyline": {
                "points": "yao|BpinvRPV@BDBXPn@\b@VPH|ChB~ChBf@ZnAr@"
              },
              "start_location": {
                "lat": 20.5623663,
                "lng": -103.4615311
              },
              "end_location": {
                "lat": 20.5594138,
                "lng": -103.4635603
              }
            },
            {
              "html_instructions": "Turn <b>left</b> onto <b>Calle Ramon Corona</b>",
              "distance": {
                "text": "0.2 km",
                "value": 204
              },
              "maneuver": "turn-left",
              "duration": {
                "text": "1 min",
                "value": 48
              },
              "travel_mode": "DRIVING",
              "polyline": {
                "points": "ion|BfvnvRb@X^m@BS?E?E@C@El@cBb@gATm@"
              },
              "start_location": {
                "lat": 20.5594138,
                "lng": -103.4635603
              },
              "end_location": {
                "lat": 20.5585096,
                "lng": -103.4621585
              }
            },
            {
              "html_instructions": "Turn <b>right</b>",
              "distance": {
                "text": "83 m",
                "value": 83
              },
              "maneuver": "turn-right",
              "duration": {
                "text": "1 min",
                "value": 22
              },
              "travel_mode": "DRIVING",
              "polyline": {
                "points": "uin|BnmnvRpCd@"
              },
              "start_location": {
                "lat": 20.5585096,
                "lng": -103.4621585
              },
              "end_location": {
                "lat": 20.5577814,
                "lng": -103.4623513
              }
            }
          ],
          "start_location": {
            "lat": 20.6301062,
            "lng": -103.4251706
          },
          "end_location": {
            "lat": 20.5577814,
            "lng": -103.4623513
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status": "OK",
  "geocoded_waypoints": [
    {
      "place_id": "ChIJp57B1EOsKIQR9oV6baimz3w",
      "geocoder_status": "OK",
      "types": [
        "street_address"
      ]
    },
    {
      "place_id": "EjlDYWxsZSBSYW1vbiBDb3JvbmEgNzA1LCA0NTY0MCBTYW4gQWd1c3TDrW4sIEphbC4sIE3DqXhpY28",
      "geocoder_status": "OK",
      "types": [
        "street_address"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```